# Problem in Server-Client application in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I am trying to create a network between a single client and a server in the localhost using javafx. The problem I have is that the console returns java.lang.NullPointerException . I wanted that the message from textField of one would be appended to the textField of the other after clicking the button. But that doesn't happen. I am new to javafx and such socket programming. I've looked into web articles and I think my problem is in the static declaration of the variables in the controller class. But I have no idea of recovering from it. The server and client are in different projects by the way. I have no clue whatsoever.

**Conroller.java of client :**

```
package sample;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

import java.awt.*;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Controller {
@FXML
private static TextField client_text_field;
@FXML
private static TextArea client_text_area = new TextArea();
static Socket s;
static DataInputStream dis;
static DataOutputStream dos;

public static void main(String[] args){
    try{
        s = new Socket("localhost",8888);
        dis = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
        dos = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
        String s2="";

        while(true){
            s2 = dis.readUTF();
            if(s2.equals("bye")) break;
            client_text_area.setText(client_text_area.getText().trim() + "\n" + "Server: " + s2);
        }
        dos.close();
        s.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}

public void send(ActionEvent event){
    try{
        String s1 = client_text_field.getText().trim();
        dos.writeUTF(s1);
        dos.flush();
        client_text_field.clear();
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
 }
}
```

**Controller.java of the server :**

```
package sample;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Controller {
@FXML
private static TextField server_text_field;
@FXML
private static TextArea server_text_area = new TextArea();
static ServerSocket ss;
static Socket s;
static DataOutputStream dos;
static DataInputStream dis;

public static void main(String[] args){
    try{
        ss = new ServerSocket(8888);
        s = ss.accept();
        dos = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
        dis = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
        String s2 = "";

        while(true){
            s2 = dis.readUTF();
            if(s2.equals("bye")) break;
            server_text_area.setText(server_text_area.getText().trim() + "\n" + s2);
        }
        dis.close();
        s.close();
        ss.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}

public void act(ActionEvent event){
    try{
        String s1 = server_text_field.getText().trim();
        dos.writeUTF(s1);
        dos.flush();
        server_text_field.clear();
    }catch(Exception p){
        System.out.println(p);
    }
 }
}
```

**fxml file of the server :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextArea?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>

<GridPane alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
   <children>
      <AnchorPane prefHeight="583.0" prefWidth="630.0">
         <children>
            <Label layoutX="262.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="54.0" text="SERVER" />
            <TextArea fx:id="server_text_area" layoutX="4.0" layoutY="41.0" prefHeight="458.0" prefWidth="619.0" />
            <TextField fx:id="server_text_field" layoutX="4.0" layoutY="521.0" prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="552.0" />
            <Button layoutX="565.0" layoutY="534.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#act" text="SEND" textFill="#1e1a97" />
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </children>
   <columnConstraints>
      <ColumnConstraints />
   </columnConstraints>
   <rowConstraints>
      <RowConstraints />
   </rowConstraints>
</GridPane>
```

**fxml file of client :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextArea?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>

<GridPane alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
   <children>
      <AnchorPane prefHeight="538.0" prefWidth="622.0">
         <children>
            <TextArea fx:id="client_text_area" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="39.0" prefHeight="397.0" prefWidth="603.0" />
            <TextField fx:id="client_text_field" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="452.0" prefHeight="74.0" prefWidth="517.0" />
            <Button layoutX="549.0" layoutY="477.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#send" text="Send" textFill="#2c2084" />
            <Label layoutX="260.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="18.0" prefWidth="50.0" text="CLIENT" textAlignment="CENTER">
               <opaqueInsets>
                  <Insets bottom="5.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" />
               </opaqueInsets>
            </Label>
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </children>
   <columnConstraints>
      <ColumnConstraints />
   </columnConstraints>
   <rowConstraints>
      <RowConstraints />
   </rowConstraints>
</GridPane>
```

The act function has been set in the onAction field of a button in the scene builder of each of the class.

Any kind of suggestion is appreciable. Thanks...

Comment: Both files are command line applications running through `main`.  You're not extending nor starting the JavaFX Application.  As such your text fields are not being initialized by either yourself, nor the FXML Application.  I suggest taking another peak at the https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/hello_world.htm or https://github.com/mmshress/JavaFX-Chat

Comment: Well @kendavidson ... I have a separate class from both server and client which loads the fxml and sets the parent . I've created the same fx project only with textarea and textfield ,without networking. It worked fine. But here I saw some web posts where it said that making variables static (textarea and textfield) caused the problem. But I can't figure out how should I solve it

Comment: @kendavidson and thanks for the links. I wanted to know if they use threading. I just want to build a simple server-client network without threads and runnable if possible in javafx .

Comment: @NehalSamee If there are other classes which load the FXML, why do the classes you’ve posted have `main()` methods?

Comment: @James_D so how should I write the controller class ?

Comment: Just like any controller you can find in any number of examples. None of them have `main()` methods

Comment: @James_D even if I remove the main() method and replace it with public non-static method, a nullpointer exception still occurs .. how would I change it ?

Comment: Your `@FXML`-annotated fields should not be static.

Comment: @James_D will only deleting the static keyword help ? Or I need to do something else ?

Comment: Your structure up to this point has been wrong, but if you make the `@FXML`-annotated fields instance variables, then assuming they’re set up correctly in the FXML they should not be null. Then you need to arrange for the controller to have a reference to whatever class is listening to the socket connection, or for both to have access to tue same data model (or somehow communicate between the two).

Comment: @James_D the only single controller class is listening or I mean connecting sockets. The codes are written there

Comment: Probably you need to update the question with the new code you have.

Comment: A controller runs in the context of the Application. If you have other code that starts the window and displays that text box then your close. You need to convert the main methods into action listeners to ui elements. The @fxml only in its the ui items when loaded in the Application. Not the main method. Just look at that second link, there is threading but that's the leas tof the issues at this point.

Comment: @kendavidson I cannot understand from the links...one says the controller class handles the ActionEvents . But here I need to connect sockets. Where should I do it ? How should I do it? Any detailed explanation would be appreciable. I cannot comprehend...

Comment: It depends how crazy you want to get. Step one would be having the controller control the socket and Tha action which writes to that socket. Step two is abstracting the socket out to another class and using it in the controller. Baby steps are OK when you're learning.